# find command sends subfolders even with maxdepth having value of 2?

Tags: find, disk-usage

I have this bash command:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 | du -h --threshold=2KB
```

and I got these results:

```
r2g: the tarball folders: 8.0K  ./cli
r2g: the tarball folders: 24K   ./dist/commands/ls
r2g: the tarball folders: 48K   ./dist/commands/add
r2g: the tarball folders: 36K   ./dist/commands/run
r2g: the tarball folders: 20K   ./dist/commands/basic
r2g: the tarball folders: 36K   ./dist/commands/config/local
r2g: the tarball folders: 36K   ./dist/commands/config/global
r2g: the tarball folders: 92K   ./dist/commands/config
r2g: the tarball folders: 4.0K  ./dist/commands/find
r2g: the tarball folders: 44K   ./dist/commands/init
r2g: the tarball folders: 272K  ./dist/commands
r2g: the tarball folders: 416K  ./dist
r2g: the tarball folders: 48K   ./assets
r2g: the tarball folders: 504K  .
```

but when this command is run by itself:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2
```

I only get this:

```
r2g: the tarball folders: ./assets
r2g: the tarball folders: ./cli
r2g: the tarball folders: ./dist
r2g: the tarball folders: ./dist/commands
```

anyone know what's going on? I guess the du command is showing subfolders, of the folders at depth 2, even though find is not explicitly pass them, I guess I have to limit du to a depth somehow?

Comment: You show that find is doing the correct thing. You show that when you add `du` it does something unexpected. So is the problem in `find` or in `du`?

Answer (score 0):

When the `du` utility is given a directory pathname, it will, by default, show the size of that directory and all its subdirectories.

When not given a directory (as in your example code), it will show the size of the current directory and all its subdirectories.

You example code will not pass anything to `du` as the `du` utility does not read from standard input.

Would you want to calculate the size of each directory, then use

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec du -h --threshold=2KB -s {} \;
```

Note that this will still include the size of each subdirectory in the calculation since `du` would recurse by itself, but with `-s` only the total size is shown.

Would you want to calculate the size of each directory while *excluding* the size of its subdirectories, then you would have to pass the filenames of the files in the directory to `du` explicitly.  This is a bit difficult to do properly, so I'm not doing that unless it's really needed (a first draft that I attempted ended up calling `find` from `find`...)